# Pasar numero de de dni de un input a otro en distinta pagina

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Necesito hacer que cuando ingreso un dni en un `input` y le doy al `boton` de aceptar, ese numero, pase a otro `input` que esta en otra pagina. He probado usar `localstorage` pero no he tenido éxito, también he ingresado esto en el html para guardar el dato pero tampoco me funciona.

```
function tomardni() {
   var dniv = localStorage.setItem("DNI");
}
```

Comment: De una página a otra dentro del mismo dominio? si es asi cual es el problema que tiene con el localStorages? te sale undefined?

Comment: claro me sale como null, estoy usando nodejs como servidor ..sisi todo dentro del mismo dominio

Comment: y si lo pasas como parámetro en la url ?

Comment: solo para aclarar `localStorage.setItem("DNI", "111111111111-1");`, es así como lo almacenas?

Comment: si así...ese dni que ingreso al principio se guarda en la base de datos mongo cuando doy aceptar en la primera pantalla, después cuando cambio de pantalla ese dni tiene que quedar guardado en un input o en el servidor para usarlo en otra cosa...no se si me explico bien..

Comment: para aclarar un poco. Primero abres página 1 y guardas en localstorage, Segundo abres página 2 y cargas desde localStorage. Es así como lo estás haciendo?

Comment: document.getElementById("DNI").innerHTML = dniv ; eso es lo que utilize en la pagina 2 para mostrar los datos

Comment: debes cargarlo desde el localStorage. Es decir, 

en página 1 `localStorage.setItem('DNI', '11111111-1');`

en página 2 `var dniv = localStorage('DNI');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podéis hacerlo de varias formas: cookies, localstorage, como parámetro por URL con js y con lenguaje de backend ya ni te cuento.

**Ejemplo con localstorage:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="txtDNI">
    <input type="button" value="Enviar" onclick="Enviar()">
</body>
<script>    
    function Enviar() {
        var dni = document.getElementById("txtDNI").value;
        console.log(dni);
        localStorage.setItem("DNI", dni);
        window.location.href = "ejem2.html";
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Hasta aquí puedes guardar el DNI, si realizamos el debug veremos como se almacena en localstorage
[image: ejem1.html]

Cuando se cargue la otra página solo necesitará invocar elemento del localstorage con GetItem y el Id que se le proporciono **DNI**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body onload="loadDNI()" >
    <input type="text" id="txtGetDNI">
</body>
<script>
    var dni = localStorage.getItem("DNI");

    function loadDNI () { document.getElementById("txtGetDNI").value = dni; }
</script>
</html>
```

Y ya se obtendrá el elemento guardado en localstorage

[image: ejem2.html]

Comment: estaba haciendo mal las declaraciones se ve...muchísimas gracias por la ayuda..!

Comment: Sí te a servido marcala como respuesta ;)

Comment: si me sirvió pero ahora me encuentro en la necesidad de pasar ese dato a varios input..he cambiado las id y asigne las variable correspondiente pero no se puede..hay alguna forma de hacerlo eso..?

Comment: En esta parte **document.getElementById("txtGetDNI").value = dni;** estoy asignando el valor obtenido del localstorage a un **input** exactamente igual se asigna a todos los inputs que quieras, solo reemplaza el **id** así **document.getElementById("txtGetDNI2").value = dni;**